# Saving HTML5 Canvas as data

Tags: wpf, html, canvas

I'd like to save the graphical elements on a HTML5 canvas to disk, do some manipulation to the data elsewhere, and then read the manipulated data abck and re-draw the canvas as it originally was. I've only found solutions where the canvas is saved as image. Is it possible to query/traverse the canvas which elements it contains? I think WPF/Silverlight have something like this.

-pom-

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to save what you are drawing in objects e.g like:

```
{"shape": "circle", "x": 45, "y": 112, "radius": 23, "color": "ff3480"}
```

then you can serialize the objects to JSON and save them on disk or in a database. You also need functionality for deserializing the JSON and draw the objects again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way. Canvas is an immediate drawing surface and nothing more. When you tell it to draw a rectangle it throws up some pixels and then forgets everything about what you've just done. If you want to keep track of anything you have to do it all yourself or else get a library that's done the same.

SVG is a retained drawing surface. Every item drawn is actually a DOM object with data representing its current state. Depending on what you're doing, using SVG would save you a lot of headaches here.

Raphael is an SVG library that might be a good starting point if you're looking to see what's already been done. Check out some of their samples:

http://raphaeljs.com/